# Html helper method for image

Tags: asp.net

I have a controller that returns an image:

```
public sealed class ImageController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult View(Guid id)
  {
    var image = _images.LoadImage(id);
    if (image == null) return HttpNotFound();
    return File(image.Data, image.Mime);
  }
}
```

At the moment I am doing this to add the `img` tag:

```
<img src="~/Image/View/@Model.ImageId" />
```

But I don't like that I am typing out the URL like that.

For other actions, there's a `Html` helper method like if I wanted a link to the image I can do:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Image", "View", "Image", new {Id = Model.ImageId})
```

Is there a way I can avoid typing out the URL for the `Img` `src`?

Comment: @KrunalPatil who says there's a database? But I see your point I could do `src="@Model.ImagePath"`

Comment: sorry, i assumed it to have a database

Comment: @KrunalPatil well it doesn't matter, the idea was good: Generate somewhere, then add to the model, I prefer that at the moment to my solution, keeps the urls out of the html and I can centralise the generation.

Comment: Good to know my stupid comment helped you.. thats what great minds do.. find solutions from stupid answers... Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own extension method :

```
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper,string imageUrl)
{
   string tag = "<img src='{0}'/>";
   tag = string.Format(tag,imageUrl);
   return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag);
}
```

Then use it like :

```
@Html.Image(@Model.ImagePath);
```

OR to use your action

```
@ { Html.RenderAction("View","Image",new {id=@Model.ImageId})}
```